# Access database split problems

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to split an Access database where I work but I have encountered a few issues that I am struggling to resolve. If I can first explain the problem.
I work for a large multi-national company that has on-site IT support but does not support Access (so no help there)
There are 12 of us working in our section, we have an old and badly designed StockMaster database on the networked F drive. The problem is that it is only set up for single users, we have to take turns using it. We aren't a computer savvy bunch, we tend to run the same named queries on a daily basis

The database is only updated once per day, every morning we get a download from our colleagues in Amsterdam. I do not want to play around with this database as first of all I'm no expert and secondly if I break it, no one will fix it.

My plan is this;
I have created a new Access database StockMaster2 that imports the required tables. Using VB coded modules, is deletes the old then imports the new. Therefore every morning it replicates what is in the original database and it works fine.
My next step is to split the database, create the front end and distribute. This is where I'm having problems.
I created the original front end StockMaster2_fe.accde and placed it in the database folder on the F:\ drive. Does every user get their own copy of the front end? I copied and saved two more front ends (copy and paste in the same folder -> rename) namely StockMaster2_alan_fe and StockMaster2_ryan_fe and tested it. I told Ryan (who sits next to me) to find the front end named after him on the F:\ drive and open it whilst I was in ...alan_fe. We both went to run macros at the same time but he was kicked out as it gave me exclusive access.
What am i doing wrong? Why is it not allowing multiple access?
My problem is that due to strict administrator privileges I cannot download any software or access the command line, so anything that I do must be done in Access itself

Comment: Sounds like a question for SuperUser

Comment: Did you split the database using the wizard? I know in my version of Access 2013 there's a split database wizard that should do the job for you (Database Tools > Move Data > Access Database) see here for more info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc

Comment: Hi, thank you all for helping me with this concern, i really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down (only because I finished all my work already...):

My next step is to split the database, create the front end and distribute. This is where i'm having problems. I created the original front end StockMaster2_fe.accde and placed it in the database folder on the F drive. Does every user get their own copy of the front end?

**Yes**

I copied and saved two more front ends (copy and paste in the same folder -> rename) namely StockMaster2_alan_fe and StockMaster2_ryan_fe and tested it. I told Ryan (who sits next to me) to find the front end named after him on the F drive and open it whilst i was in ...alan_fe. We both went to run macros at the same time but he was kicked out as it gave me exclusive access. What am i doing wrong?

**Ensure your back end contains *only* tables.  Access is a "client-centric" database, which means when a query is run it pulls all of the data over the pipe to your local computer, does what it does, and then sends it back.  So, make sure the back end has only tables and all the other jazz (macros, queries, etc...) are in the front end.  Also, the front end will contain *links* to the back-end tables.  All of your queries/macros/etc.. will reference these links, and not the tables in the back-end DB directly.**

Why is it not allowing multiple access?

**Also, make sure your table-locking scheme is multi-user friendly.  If you're doing table locking, it will cause errors.  If you're doing record locking, it probably won't.**

My problem is that due to strict administrator privileges i cannot download any software or access the command line, so anything that i do must be done in Access itself.

**Shouldn't be a problem at all.**

Comment: Hi Johnny, thank you for your reply. The whole issue has become frustrating because i thought i'd done everything right but still encountered problems. That's why i've gone back to basics just to confirm that i am actually doing what i should be doing. Just to confirm, table locking as in File -> options -> client setting -> advanced default open mode is shared, default record locking is 'no locks'. Is there anything else? I'm wondering if there's a box i need to tick so where or something else simple

Comment: Sounds right.  I've used this schema for over a decade and never had problems with it, so I'm not sure why it's not functioning as expected.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I think I may have made a school boy error as previously I have put queries and macros in the database before splitting it. I am hoping (time allowing) to create the new database on Monday and trial it then. Fingers crossed it will work, i will feedback accordingly.Thanks again for all of the help and support. Alan

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not seeing this post sooner to end your agony.  There are two absolute main issues that must be resolved to get you on the right track.  First, and perhaps the most important, is that your file has the name of  StockMaster2_fe.accde.  The extension, the accde, is the executable version.  Design changes cannot be made to that version.  The extension should say .accdb to provide you with all the flexibility to alter the database, create one database for back-end tables, and a second database for front-end objects to include queries, forms, reports, macros and modules.  If you have the accdb version, then your work will start to get much easier.

Issue number two, if your team is not able to share the database, then that is a sign that the database, when first opening, is opening in Exclusive mode.  This option can be changed in the Access Options, in the Advance menu, under Advanced section.  Look for Default open mode.  It should say Shared to have multiple users operating all at once.

A possible hidden issue that can be happening, is that the database has VBA code which informs the database to open exclusively.  With your version of the accde, you will not be able to access that code or change how the database opens.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I was transferred to another department before I could implement the database. I have promised to return to fix the problem. My plan was to create a new database that updates from the original,  as the original is a bloated mess. Thanks for the advice,  your help is most appreciated. Alan